# Zoom and scale css background image

Tags: html, css

I'd like to zoom and scale in the castle when screen becomes smaller. If I set a fixed height, the background is deformed.
What can I try ?
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/uro8x66a/)

```
<div class="background_cover">
<img src="http://www.cdtl.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Walt_disney_pictures.jpg">
</div>

.background_cover img {
    height: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are defining background properties, but you don't have a background, you have an image. You can make a little trick with visibility:

```css
.background_cover {
  background-image: url(http://www.cdtl.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Walt_disney_pictures.jpg);
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.background_cover img {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="background_cover">
  <img src="http://www.cdtl.fr/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Walt_disney_pictures.jpg">
</div>
```

See your edited fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/uro8x66a/1/

Comment: No, the image will be cached to use in the same document, since the URL is exactly the same (without timestamp or version added). You can test it in the fiddle, there are only one request for the same image. You can use infinitelly in the same document.

Comment: Thanks! But I would like to "focus" the image in the castle in responsive mode. Like a zoom, when the page is resized.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, if you have to use the image tag instead of a background. The image scales on hover using the transform property.
The container has overflow hidden and crops the image.

```
.background_cover {
    overflow:hidden;
}
.background_cover img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

I forked your JSFiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/tgLhevrd/1/